# Cannot figure out this wildcard subdomain mishap

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I've been trying to accomplish this for hours now and for some reason it does not want to work.

All I want is username.domain.com to internally go to domain.com/users/username

I set-up my dns that the wildcard subdomain points towards public_html/wild folder and I placed an index.html file in there and all seems to work well.

The problem is when I use this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php($|/) index.php/users/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

It shows a 404 page not found error. I checked the logs and it says it still looks in the /wild folder, however my script is one level up in the public_html folder.

How can I fix this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You say you've pointed the wildcard subdomain to `public_html/wild`, which means when someone requests `http://user.domain.com/` the **/** request is mapped to `public_html/wild`. This means a request for the wildcard subdomain will never be able to get mapped to anything in the parent directory `public_html` (that's why it's called a document *root*).

One of the things you can do is point the document root of the wildcard subdomains to the same place as the main domain, the place where `index.php` is. But if you've got content from the main domain that you don't want to get mixed into the subdomains or vice versa, you could try using the `P` flag which utilizes mod_proxy and creates a reverse proxy:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php($|/) http://www.domain.com/index.php/users/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping, however I get the following error:

Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /users/www/users/www/users/www/users/www/users/www/users/www/users/myusername/.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: www.domain.com

Additionally, a 502 Bad Gateway error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: In addition, if it matters, I am using CodeIniter, but everything is setup properly as domain.com/users/username works just fine.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming this .htaccess file belongs in the wild folder and not the public_html folder as there is one there as well, it's simply removing the index.php file for clean codeigniter urls.

Comment: @user1993382 accidentally forgot the first condition, bad copy/paste

Comment: thank you, however it still points towards domain.com/wild instead of just domain.com and I still get a 404 not found error.

If i remove the end of the uri and just leave the domain on that last line it loads the domain/wild folders index file that i placed there.

is there a way for me to remove that wild from there and have it go straight to my main url?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.myserver\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^m/$)^.*$ http://myserver.com/m/sites/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,P]
```